# Where should custom (and rarly occuring) exceptions be defined?

Tags: java, oop, exception

Where should custom exception be defined which are only thrown by one single method? It would be perfect if I could write them as local classes but then I can't throw them since they can't be resolved to a Type...

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a class nested in the class in which that method is defined. Don't forget to make your exception class static.

Comment: That would be the next best thing... so there is absolutely no possibility to define it inside the Method?

Comment: No. If you want to be able to catch the custom exception (or declare that your method throws the custom exception), the symbol needs to be visible outside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create them as a nested class in which that method is defined:

```
class MyClass {
  void myMethod() throws MyCustomException {}

  static class MyCustomException extends Exception {}
}
```

Note in this case that the custom exception class needs to be `static` in order to honour `Throwable`'s `Serializable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your exception inner class static, this way you will be able to use it outside the main class.

Another solution would be just using one of existing general exception types, list of all of them under "Direct Known Subclasses": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html